# German residency for dependents when leaving for studying abroad

Tags: germany, blue-card, dependent-visa

I moved recently together with my husband and son to Germany (we are non-EU).
I have a Blue Card so We were able to move as a family. We enrolled our son in the 1st grade of the nearby school.

For personal reasons, my husband and son are moving back to our home country, so my son is going to leave school here in Germany and get back to school in our home country.

As I got a Blue Card residency, they got their residency permits as dependents to me, each got a 3 years residency.

We plan to exchange visits, so they must still be able to come to Germany (We plan for them not to stay 6 month uninterrupted outside of Germany, we knew about this condition).

Now I am afraid if my son de-register from school here, his residency will be revoked.

Can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am afraid if my son de-register from school here, his residency will be revoked.

This fear is justified, since your son will be leaving 'for a reason which is not temporary in nature'.

> We plan to exchange visits, so they must still be able to come to Germany ...

These are **visits** and therefore not a *resumption of an interupted residence*.

A multi-entry Schengen Visa (type C) would serve the same purpose.

> ... (We plan for them not to stay 6 month uninterrupted outside of Germany, we knew about this condition).

For a EU Blue Card holder and their dependants the period is **12 months**.

This is a matter for which you should contact the Immigration Office, so that they are aware of the situation.

This could result in either them saying that they don't mind **or** to ensure that a multi-entry Schengen Visa would be issued the first time around.

---

**Sources**:

- [Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory Residence Act (AufenthG) - Index](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/index.html)

  - [§51 - Termination of lawful residence; continued validity of restrictions](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050)

    - (1)(6) if the foreigner leaves the federal territory for a reason **which is not temporary in nature**,
    - (1)(7) if the foreigner leaves the federal territory and does not re-enter the federal territory within six months or within a longer period set by the foreigners authority,
    - (10) In derogation from subsection (1) no. 7, the period for the EU Blue Card and the temporary residence permits pursuant to sections 30, 32, 33 or 36 issued to **dependants of EU Blue Card** holders is **12 months**. The same applies to the permanent settlement permit of a foreigner who has resided lawfully in the federal territory for at least 15 years and to the permanent settlement permit of a spouse cohabiting with the foreigner if they are 60 years of age or older.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this contradicts the Section 34 of child right to reside when being dependent to a resident parents: [link](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0814) `Act of Residency`

Comment: @AsliFamily By moving back to your home country, your husband and son will no longer be exercising that right. No idea how much leeway the officials have in such matters. That is why you should contact them and ask.